# Directive 'register_long_arrays,how to modify?mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, sql, directive, mysql-num-rows

Directive 'register_long_arrays, in Php 5.3.28,
warning appear :
mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in xxx/mysql.php on line 534

534 which refer to this row :$count = mysql_num_rows($resource);

```
function CountResult($resource=null)
{
    if ($resource === null) {
        $this->SetError('Resource is a null object');
        return false;
    }
    if (!is_resource($resource)) {
        $resource = $this->Query($resource);
    }
    $count = mysql_num_rows($resource);
    return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exept that `mysql_num_rows` is deprecated in php 5.5.0 , I mean that is better to use `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySLQ` extension; however `mysql_num_rows` needs a `resource` object, not a boolean as  the error message says. Try to check your conditions statements in order to pass the right parameter to `mysql_num_rows` function.